# Dynamic visualization bokeh

Tags: javascript, python, dynamic, visualization, bokeh

I want to represent the result of an Isomap algorithm. But I also want the user to choose the number of components he wants to keep.
I create a slider object for that but the thing is that the callback function is in Javascript. Therefore I can't use scikit learn to update my data.
This is my code, someone could give some ideas ?
Thank you

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import vform
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider
from sklearn import manifold

output_file("test.html")


X = np.random.randn(1000,20)

Y = np.random.randn(1000,20)

X_isomap = manifold.Isomap(n_neighbors=10, n_components=2).fit_transform(X)

X1 = X_isomap[:,0]
X2 = X_isomap[:,1]

IsoSource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=X1, y=X2,DATA=X))

plot1 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,tools = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,resize")
plot1.circle('x', 'y',source=IsoSource,size=7, color="navy")


#sliderCompMDS = Slider(title="n_components MDS",value=2,start=2,end=20,step=1)


callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=IsoSource),code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value')
    x = data['x']
    y =data['y']
    X = data['DATA']
    donnees = manifold.Isomap(n_neighbors=10, n_components=f).fit_transform(X)
    x = donnees[:,0]
    y = donnees[:,1]
    source.trigger('change');

    """)

sliderCompIso = Slider(title="n_components Isomap",value=2,start=1,end=20,step=1,callback=callback)



layout = vform(sliderCompIso, plot1)

show(layout)
```

Comment: If you want to trigger *python* code from user interactions, you will need to create a Bokeh server app. As you have noted, `CustomJS` callbacks can only execute JavaScript, not python. You can see several examples here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app (click on an image to go to a live running version of the app) as well as find lots of documentation here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your links.
It helped me solve my problem

Comment: @clémentabinader Well, how about you...share your insights? NOthing mroe frustrating than seeing someone ask the exact same questions but keeping all knowledge that resulted to themselves.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is always better to update the entire `.data` dict at once. So, ***don't*** do this:

```
source2.data['y1'] = Y_MDS[:,0]
source2.data['y2'] = Y_MDS[:,1]
```

Instead make a `newdict` with the data first, then do

```
source2.data = newdata
```

Beyond that, it's hard to say. It looks like you are sending ~1000 x-y points on each update? That's not an unreasonable number, and many examples show more than that. Are you certain that the computation itself is not taking an appreciable amount of time? How long do:

```
manifold.Isomap(n_components=w).fit_transform(X)
```

and

```
manifold.MDS(n_components=u).fit_transform(Y)
```

take to finish, on their own?

My guess is that those simply take some amount of time to compute. If that is the case, there's not anything Bokeh will be able to do. In `0.12` there should be a "busy" message added to the protocol, so the app can visually indicate that expensive computation is happening.

Comment: I checked the computation time of the MDS and realized all my issues came from that. (I needed 36 seconds to generate the webpage and the MDS needed 34 seconds) 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Great! As I mentioned, `0.12` should have some new visual indicators that help with showing users when things are "busy"